# VBA - autofill and increment from the last non - empty cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code:

```
Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("A" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).AutoFill Destination:=Range("A2000:A" & lastRow)
```

It works fine. It finds the the last non - empty cell in column B and then starts to Autofill column A from A2000 to the cell in question in column B.
However I need it to start AutoFill from the last non - empty cell in column A even if there is only one empty row to be auto-filed. This is important as usually I have only one empty cell between column A and column B, which means there may be other decision as AutoFillNext or similar.
I tried to modify the code just by removing the cell number, like this:

```
Destination:=Range("A:A" & lastRow)
```

It doesn't work as expected.

Comment: It might be easier/more clear if you create a `lastRow` variable, and do like `lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count,1).End(XlUp).Row`, and use that as the starting place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tend to use the [Range.FillDown method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838404.aspx) rather than the [Range.AutoFill method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195345.aspx).

```
Dim lastRow As Long
with activesheet
    lastRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    .Range(.Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp), .Cells(lastRow, "A")).FillDown
end with
```

If you are trying to increment a date value then a [Range.DataSeries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839262.aspx) would be more appropriate.

```
Dim lastRow As Long
With ActiveSheet
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    With .Range(.Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp), .Cells(lastRow, "A"))
        .DataSeries Rowcol:=xlColumns, Type:=xlChronological, _
                    Date:=xlDay, Step:=1, Trend:=False
    End With
End With
```

Comment: It works. However it copies the result instead of increment it. In column A I`m storing dates. By just dragging down the last date available I increment it as well. This is the original way I use to record the macro and AutoFill is the VBA suggestion. Afterwards I modified the code but not so to change the AutoFill.

Comment: See revision above. The incremented date might have been something to mention in the original question; perhaps you can edit your original question to reflect that.